# bootstrap-wysihtml5 createLink issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, editor, wysihtml5

I am using [this](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5) everything works quite well, except :

When I click on link button, I get the following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:6936
_format _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:6936
wysihtml5.commands.createLink.exec _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:6970
wysihtml5.Commands.Base.extend.exec _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:6793
wysihtml5.toolbar.Toolbar.Base.extend._execCommand _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:9180
wysihtml5.toolbar.Toolbar.Base.extend.execCommand _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:9172
(anonymous function) _wysihtml5-0.3.0.js?body=1:9221
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks before for everyone's help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works with me.
you must include all required css and js file ( including http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js)

i updated a `fiddle` for your reference

please visit http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/vNPAJ/

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and found that the problem was because the create link dialog div element was not enclosed in the toolbar div.